# After Reboot Ubuntu 20.04 - RAID10 goes INACTIVE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, raid10

I installed RAID 10 on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04

By the Following commands:

```
1. mdadm --examine /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf

sudo parted /dev/sdc mklabel gpt
sudo parted /dev/sdd mklabel gpt
sudo parted /dev/sde mklabel gpt
sudo parted /dev/sdf mklabel gpt

sudo parted -a opt /dev/sdc mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sdd mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sde mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
sudo parted -a opt /dev/sdf mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%


6. mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1

7. cat /proc/mdstat
8. mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
9. mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid10/

10. nano /etc/fstab
/dev/md0                /mnt/raid10              ext4    defaults        0 0

mount -a
mount -av

12. mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Even save all config, after reboot RAID goes inactive-array

Also change name to something /dev/md126 etc.

This is only Happens with Ubuntu 20.04
With Ubuntu 18.04 Working  Good.

If I use, Raid restart.

```
`mdadm --stop /dev/md0`

    mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a partition .eg sdc1 ,sdd1 ,sde1 ,sdf1 but the mdadm command is using the whole disk without using the partition you created.
If you are trying to use partition
the command should be

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
```

also to copy the partition to  all disk so they are the same you can use

```
sgdisk -R <New_Disk> <Existing_Disk>
```

Be careful first disk is the new one.This seem the wrong way around

also

```
sgdisk -G /dev/sdd
```

will create a new GUID on the disks ( not sure if this is needed)

after creating partitions I would reboot before creating array. Hope this helps.